# Good Comprehensive Maths Dictionary

Tags: terminology, definition

I'm looking for a dictionary that contains definitions for lots of advanced maths terms like Lie Groups, Galois Theory, Green's Function, operators etc. Preferably the definitions be relatively easy to understand (for A level/university students) and without too much jargon. I've found one just called "Mathematics dictionary" by Robert James. Is that any good? Are there any you would recommend?

I'm asking this because I'm finding it impossible to learn about more complex topics on Wikipedia without going into an infinite amount of rabbit holes trying to understand the terms they use. The simpler version of wikipedia is great but isn't there for most advanced topics. Any alternative advice would be welcome!

Comment: Google search encyclopedia of mathematics

Comment: I think that James book is very old and also not as advanced as you want.

Comment: It will be really quite hard to actually learn any complex topics without confronting the technical aspects of the prerequisite definitions and concepts. I don't think this differs between Wikipedia or any other source. If you really want to start learning a university-level topic in maths, I would say you're best off reading a full set of lecture notes (there are many of these on the internet!) or a textbook, and making sure you know all the prerequisites that this text mentions. Then any concepts you need will be introduced in order. But this is quite ambitious if you're not studying maths!

Comment: You may want to look at the encyclopedia mentioned in the mathoverflow question [EDM2 (Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics from Japan Math. Soc.) and updates](https://mathoverflow.net/q/427757/15780).